# select properties of entity ef linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have query for a list of objects (ex Rooms) that contains an object (ex Door) 
Door has many properties (ex width, height, color), but i only need color.

now i have

```
Rooms.include(r => r.Door)
```

but this takes all properties of door.
if i do

```
Rooms.include(r => r.Door.color)
```

than it says that color is not a navigational property of door.

How can i only select color ?

i hope i made myself clear. any help is appreciated

Comment: You want rooms loaded, or just list of door colors without any info about rooms?

Answer (score 1):

Include is not used for selecting, it is used to tell the compiler that the property should be included in the query.  Just use a select to get the color and include Rooms in the select.

Edit: Answer was edited after additional information was provided.

```
Rooms.Select(r => new { Color = r.Door.color, Room = r });
```

Comment: That will select only door colors instead of rooms

Comment: as stated in the comment of Sergey, this only selects color so the return type does not match a list of rooms anymore

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, I answered before the additional information was provided.

Comment: @JaceRhea I believe `Include` will add full `Door` object to room you are selecting

Comment: @JaceRhea I have dejavu :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot conditionally load properties of related entity - you either load whole door entity, or don't include that entity. But you can use anonymous type to return room and color of it's door:

```
 var rooms = from r in db.Rooms
             select new {
                 Room = r,
                 DoorColor = r.Door.Color
             };
```

Comment: Not just anonymous. If the entity has public properties he could just cast it to another Door object using a Select statement and a collection initializer.

Comment: gues i need to return a list of custom view with different properties instead of the aggregate room than . thx for the help

Comment: @Flater can you elaborate on collection initializer you are mentioning?

Comment: A collection initilaizer is what you use for anonymous types. `Rooms.Select(x => new Room { Door = x.Door, Id = x.Id});` The thing in {brackets} is a collection initializer. That example works if the Room class has *public properties*.

Comment: @Flater that's an object initializer. Different thing

Comment: Yep, you're right, sorry. I don't use the terms all that often, but should've realized.

Comment: @Flater sorry was AFK. Didn't check that, but I think with EF you will not be able to construct complex type in select statement

Comment: Not sure about complex types. But entities work though, I've implemented this in the past. It's possible though that this was after already having called a `.ToList()` on the collection, so it's just a local cast when you run the `.Select()`. Can't be sure anymore.