# Return Selected Properties of Single Object in EF Method Syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
        //This works, but seems incorrect to me
        Object selection = db.ExampleTable
                             .Where(s => s.Id == id)
                             .Select(s => new { s.Id, s.PropIWantToShow })
                             .SingleOrDefault();

        //This seems correct, but does not work
        Object selection = db.ExampleTable
                              .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)
                              .Select(s => new { s.Id, s.PropIWantToShow });
```

`db` is our Entity Framework data context.

My goal is to select a single entry matching the provided id in ExampleTable. If an entry is not found, this is to return null. However, EF doesn't seem to let me select a single object and then only return specific properties. How do I accomplish this or is the first example I provided correct?

I did check this question:
[select properties of entity ef linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094315/select-properties-of-entity-ef-linq):

> Unfortunately you cannot conditionally load properties of related entity - you either load whole door entity, or don't include that entity.

But the answer just doesn't seem right, but obviously "seems" is a very weak statement.

Comment: FIrst selection is good enough, except declaring your variable as `Object`. You'd better use `var` for anonymous types

Comment: your problem is `SingleOrDefault` returns an item, not an `IEnumerable`, so you cant use LINQ against it

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the first piece of code?

Comment: .Where seems to indicate that I am selecting a list / enumerable / queryable / whatever, rather than a single item, that was my source of concern. I will totally read your book btw...one of these days. Edit - also, thanks you for the replies Serhi and Jones, I just had to reply to John first, him being John and all.

Comment: Your first method is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @RobertMcKee My source of confusion comes from the fact that if I was selecting one ENTIRE object, I would just go with ".Single(obj=>obj.Id=9999).

Comment: But that gets you a single object, not an `IQueryable<T>` object that LINQ would work with.  If you want to convert from one type of object to another, that isn't a LINQ thing.  You can still, but it'll be more convoluted.  Something like: `var selection =...; var newselection=new {Id=selection.Id,PropIWantToShow=selection.PropIWantToShow};`  but this is very bad because you DID retrieve the entire object from the DB, and then just threw away most of it.  You first method only returns 2 fields from the DB.

Comment: Alright, thanks, if you want to type that comment up in a quick answer, I will accept it. I guess I need to learn LINQ better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method is correct:

```
    //This works, but seems incorrect to me
    Object selection = db.ExampleTable
                         .Where(s => s.Id == id)
                         .Select(s => new { s.Id, s.PropIWantToShow })
                         .SingleOrDefault();
```

Your second method gets you a single object, not an `IQueryable<T>` object that LINQ would work with. If you want to convert from one type of object to another, that isn't a LINQ thing. You can still, but it'll be more convoluted. Something like:

```
var selection =...; 
var newselection=new { Id=selection.Id, PropIWantToShow=selection.PropIWantToShow };
```

but this is very bad because you DID retrieve the entire object from the DB, and then just threw away most of it. Your first method only returns 2 fields from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function to return null if condition doesn't match then use `FirstorDefault()` instead of `SingleorDefalut()`. So if you want to match an id and return an object then do it like this :

```
return db.ExampleTable.FirstorDefault(c=>c.Id == id);
```

Comment: Ugh... why would you say something like this? SingleOrDefault() will still return null when no object matches the condition. The only difference between the two calls is that SingleOrDefault() will throw an (expected) Exception when there are multiple elements matching the condition. EDIT: After some thinking, there is another difference between the two calls: FirstOrDefault will only run through the table until an element is found and then return, SingleOrDefault will run through the table until a second element is found.